# Power Query combine three external Excel source files and append specific columns

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I'm trying to create a lookup table combining the my 3 source files primary keys columns, this way I won't have to do an outer join to find the missing records from each source and then append them together.  I've found how to "combine" two source files but I can't figure out how to drill into the columns/fields lists so that I can select only Column 1 (or "Item Code" header name in the Excel files).

Here is the code I have so far to combine 2/3 files (as a trial):

```
let
Source = Table.Combine({Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Desktop\Dry Good Demad-Supply Report\MRP_ParentDmd\Data_Sources\JDE_MRP_Dmd.xlsx"), null, true), 

Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\Desktop\Dry Good Demad-Supply Report\MRP_ParentDmd\Data_Sources\JDE_Open_PO.xlsx"), null, true)})

in Source
```

Comment: This should be a comment but I do not have enough reputation to do so yet: - 1) Could you provide more information, examples of your files ?
- 2) Also I would advise to try doing tests without power query, through the interface, (ex: append queries...) and study the resulting Power Query code in the advanced editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a less than ideal data source (ie lots of irrelevant columns, duplicates in the data you want) then one way to avoid materialising a whole bunch of unnecessary data would be to perform all your transformations/filtering on nested table cells rather than loading all the data up just to remove columns/dupes.

The M code below should be a rough start that hopefully gets you on the way

```
let
    //Adjust the Source step to refer to the relevant folder your 3 source files are saved in
    Source = Folder.Files("CC:\Users\Desktop\Dry Good Demad-Supply Report\MRP_ParentDmd\Data_Sources"),

    //Filter the file list to leave just your 3 source files if required
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Extension] = ".xlsx")),

    //Remove all columns excep the Binary file column
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Content"}),

    //Convert the binary file to the file data ie sheets, tables, named ranges etc - the same data you get when you use a file as a source
    #"Workbook Data" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Removed Other Columns",{"Content", each Excel.Workbook(_)}), 

    //Filter the nested file data table cell to select the sheet you need from your source files - may not be necessary depending on what's in the files
    #"Sheet Filter" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Workbook Data",{"Content", each Table.SelectRows(_, each [Name] = "Sheet1")}),     

    //Step to Name the column you want to extract data from
    #"Column Name" = "Column1",

    //Extract a List of the values in the specified column
    #"Column Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sheet Filter",{"Content", each List.Distinct(Table.Column(_{0}[Data],#"Column Name"))}), 

    //Expand all the lists
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Column Values", "Content"),

    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded Content")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

**EDIT**
To select multiple columns and provide the distinct rows you could change the steps starting from the `#"Column Name"`

This could end up taking a fair bit longer than the previous step depending on how much data you have, but it should do the job

```
    //Step to Name the column you want to extract data from
    #"Column Name" = {"Column1","Column2","Column5"},

    //Extract a List of the values in the specified column
    #"Column Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sheet Filter",{"Content", each Table.SelectColumns(_{0}[Data],#"Column Name")}),

    //In each nested table, filter down to distinct rows
    #"Distinct rows in Nested Tables" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Column Values",{"Content", each Table.Distinct(_)}),

    //Expand nested table column
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Distinct rows in Nested Tables", "Content", #"Column Name"), 

    //Remove Duplicates in combined table
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Expanded Content")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

Comment: Thanks Ben the code you provided is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Hi Ben, just curious if I wanted to add more columns from my data sources would I need to adjust the #Column Name section?  I've been searching but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Do you mean you want to get a single distinct list of values (from multiple different columns in several files) or a table with all the distinct rows from x columns from your files?

Comment: You came through again for me Ben, thanks.  I tried adding the array in #Column Name like you did but, kept getting an error.  I had a feeling there was additional step that needed to be added, looks like it was the "Distinct rows in Nested Tables" part.  Thanks for your patience with me, I'm still figuring out M code and Stack Overflow for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

If you're starting out with Power Query, don't try to write your code manually and don't cram everything into one statement. Rather, use the ribbon commands and then edit the code if required.

For your scenario, you could create a separate query for each data source. Load these as connections only. Shape each data source to contain the columns you need. Then you can append the three data queries and further refine the result.

Comment: Hi teylyn, Thank you for your feedback.  I have some experience with Power Query/BI with other projects but, what I'm trying to do here is something I would do in Access SQL in which I could 'Union' these tables/columns, get distinct records and use the consolidated union table as a lookup table.  Is there something similar in Power Query?  I could easily append these three data sources but, two of them have over 100k rows and the value data is structured horizontal.  I want to avoid bringing unnecessary data in twice.

Comment: I don't know what Access SQL is. It seems to be a contradiction in terms. If you want to combine data from different Excel files into one query, you will need to load all the data into Excel to do that. There is no magic way around that.